# Adjust height of div only if child element has class X

Tags: css, sass

```
.embed {
   height: 100px
}
```

How can I adjust the height of the **div container**, only when the iframe class is `my-iframe`

```
<div class="embed">
   <iframe class="my-iframe">
</div>
```

I do NOT want it to adjust the height in the following case:

```
<div class="embed">
   <iframe class="some-other-iframe">
</div>
```

Is it possible to do so in **SASS or CSS**?

Comment: Change the height of the iframe using the class, and the parent will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you increase the height of the iframe the parent div will also increase as long as the isn't already a height specified for the div.
You can increase the height of the iframe doing this

```
iframe[class*="my-iframe"]{
   height: 500px /*or whatever height you want*/
}
```

This will target only the iframe that contains the class "my-iframe".